# Python libraries in Eclipse?

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, pydev

I am used to work with python but i have a project which requires Java, is there any way to use Python libraries ( Sklearn , Tensorflow , Pandas, Numpy ...) in Java IDE for example Ecplise.

If you have any idea about using python libraries in java enviroment, it would be a great help for me.

Thank you guys.

Comment: There's a reason why they are called Python libraries and not Java libraries.

Comment: There's Jython but that would be skirting around the requirement to use Java. What's the reason for the Java requirement? Is it practical (in which case it would help to know it) or it's just a customer's whim?

Comment: Yes  exactly it is a customer requirement. In fact, the company has developed a software using Java since a long time ago and now they want to introduce some machine learning, so the manager wanted to use Java but he is open to any solution if i want to use Python instead. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You dont need it to be in the same project/IDE for it to send data from python scripts to java applications and the other way. Try making some endpoints that the other can access and get data from. Java or python is only a language and in the end it all becomes zeroes and ones.